# KTable not deduplicating the incoming records with same keys

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am trying to deduplicate the records using input topic as KTable and sinking them to output topic. But the KTable is still sinking the duplicate records to the output topic. Not  sure where am I going wrong.

Here is my application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        bindings:
          process-in-0: input.topic
          process-out-0: output.topic
        definition: process
      kafka:
        streams:
          bindings:
            process-in-0:
              consumer:
                materializedAs: incoming-store
          binder:
            application-id: spring-cloud-uppercase-app
            brokers: localhost:9092
            configuration:
              commit:
                interval:
                  ms: 1000
                state.dir: state-store
              default:
                key:
                  serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
                value:
                  serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
```

As per the spring cloud stream kafka stream [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.1.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_state_store) about state store, I have added the materialized view above as `incoming-store`

The process() bean function takes the input topic as KTable and and sink it to output topic

```java
    @Bean
    public Function<KTable<String, String>, KStream<String, String>> process(){
        return table -> table
                .toStream()
                .peek((k, v) -> log.info("Received key={}, value={}", k, v));
    }
```

For a given input of 4 records

```
key=111, value="a"
key=111, value="a"
key=222, value="b"
key=111, value="a"
```

I am expecting to get only 2 records

```
key=111, value="a"
key=222, value="b"
```

But getting all the 4 records. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: I would solve this by aggregating events based on the `key` and with a time window

Comment: Based on your comentaries I am not sure what you are trying to do. Are you trying to compact events without transform them using `KStream` https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.1.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-tombstones ?

Comment: I am trying to keep only the latest update for a given event. So, if I get the same record with key=111, then I need to keep the latest record. I can do this by converting the stream to KTable something similar to [https://kafka-tutorials.confluent.io/kafka-streams-convert-to-ktable/kstreams.html](https://kafka-tutorials.confluent.io/kafka-streams-convert-to-ktable/kstreams.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by a key and aggregate the events. Although you are not concatenating the strings during the aggregation process, the `aggregate` transformation will be used just to emit the values that you are grouping by the keys `111` or `222`. Your use case is just a distinct aggregation. Every time that you aggregate you will receive `(key, value, aggregate)`, then you keep only the `value` that it will be the latest value.

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class KafkaAggFunctionalService {

    @Bean
    public Function<KTable<String, String>, KStream<String, String>> aggregate() {
        return table -> table
                .toStream()
                .groupBy((key, value) -> key, Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
                .aggregate(() -> "", (key, value, aggregate) ->
                                value,
                        Materialized.<String, String, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("test-events-snapshots").withKeySerde(Serdes.String()).withValueSerde(Serdes.String())
                )
                .toStream()
                .peek((k, v) -> log.info("Received key={}, value={}", k, v));
    }
}
```

This [git repo](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/main/kafka-streams-samples) has a lot of examples. The one that [looks very similar to yours is this](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/main/kafka-streams-samples/kafka-streams-aggregate/src/main/java/kafka/streams/table/join/KafkaStreamsAggregateSample.java).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem that you are trying to solve, will be well solved by compacted topic here.
Once you deliver data with the same key to a compacted topic and compaction is enabled on broker level (which is enabled by default), each broker will start a compaction manager thread and a number of compaction threads. These are responsible for performing the compaction tasks.
Compaction does nothing but keeps the latest values of each key and cleans up the older (dirty) entries.

Refer [this](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compaction) Kafka Documentation for more details.

Comment: I am using spring-cloud stream which abstracts the KTable<String, String> table =streamBuilder.toTable("input.topic"); into Function<KTable<String, String>... so, yes I am using log compaction. However, the log compaction does not seem to be working. That's what the main issue I am referring in my question.

Comment: Have you verified your output topic's configuration, is it a compacted topic ?

Comment: I am using KTable that abstraction in my stream application on the input topic and I am converting it to KStream to sink the result to the output topic, So I don't want to configure the output topic to be log compacted with any configuration like --config "cleanup.policy=compact". The question is about the cloud kafka binder not accepting the ktable input.